# Error "insufficient priviliges" when trying to insert into an SQL table

Tags: oracle, jdbc

> I am trying to insert data into a table but it says "Insufficient privilages" to be exact it gives me "Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01031: insufficient privilieges" Error, i am unable to figure it out.also i have created a table before inserting an update. here is my code

```
package advanced;
import java.sql.*;
public class Insertion 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    System.out.println("Driver successfully loaded");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","SYSTEM","2605");
    System.out.println("Successfully connected");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    System.out.println("Statement successfully created");
    int res;
    res = stmt.executeUpdate("insert into SYS.employee values(201,'Hamed','Bangalore','Engineer',57485)");

    res = stmt.executeUpdate("insert into SYS.employee values(301,'SURESH','Madras','Doctor',7475)");

    res = stmt.executeUpdate("insert into SYS.employee values(401,'RAHUL','Bombay','Engineer',45645)");
        System.out.println("Records inserted");

        stmt.close();
        con.close();    

}

}
```

Comment: Do the SQL statements work via the command line oracle client? Does the user you are connecting to the database with have database and table privileges for SYS.employee?

Comment: You **never** put your own objects in the SYS schema! Fix that, only put your data in your own schemas.

Comment: Oh i am so sry for replying so late, i actually figured it out myself,but when i opened my account today i saw the same solution,anyways thanx a lot @Mat  :) :)